# Why does this delete information from both jsons

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I try to delete information from a JSON but when i put the og JSON to a new variable and then delete some of the information from both

example:

```
fs = require('fs');
var name = 'Assets/signup.json';
var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name).toString());
const originalJSON = m;

let newJSONFile = originalJSON;
console.log(originalJSON)
            
newJSONFile.members.splice(0, newJSONFile.members.length)

console.log(originalJSON)
```

so this code should from what i know that it will asign a new JSON and then delete the members from newJSONFile and keep the members in the originalJSON but when i console.log(originalJSON) it output the members to be empty and i dont understand why

Comment: `let newJSONFile = originalJSON;` does not create a new copy of the originalJSON object. Its simply creates a reference.

Comment: ok so is there a way that i can do something like that? like let newJSONFIle = new JSON or something

Comment: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: The answer vaibhavmande gave you is correct, but it's missing the fact your object actually contains an array. Basicaly you're modifiying both objects, as both are references tp the same object in memory. One way to create a distinct copy would be te keep the text content of your file **before** parsing it, and then parsing it into each variable: `const file = fs.readFileSync(name).toString()` and then `const original = JSON.parse(file)` and `const new = JSON.parse(file)`. This will create different objects with the same props, which you can then update independently without modifying the

Comment: JSON stringifying something and parsing it back to an object has been a long standing way of creating copies of objects. To create shallow copies of an object, you can also use destructuring `const copy = {...original}` or Object.assign: `const copy = Object.assign({}, original)` but it all depends on how complex your object is. Since your JSON file contains an array, which is exactly what you want to modify, both the destructuring and the Object.assign methods won't work, as **they will just copy the reference to the original array** within the copy

Answer (score 2):

What looks like is your `newJSONFile` and `originalJSON` are both the same.

The objects in JS, they refer to same location. Unlike primitives we cant make a copy simply by using `=`. You can read more about it [here](https://javascript.info/object-copy)

We can create deep copies using spread and other ways `const newJSONFile = {...originalJSON}` but this will still not deep copy the nested objects.

I am not aware of the structure your JSON is so can't suggest best way to create a deep copy.

You can use clone functions from libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

Create a deep clone of your original JSON, instead of just creating a reference. Then you can delete from the clone, and retain the original:

```
/* YOUR JSON FILE */

const newJSON = {
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "available": "true",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "TinyruthlessPC",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Tester",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tinyruthless",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Photography",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kade",
      "instagram": "Kade_Sucks",
      "signupDate":"April 11, 2021"
    }
  ]
}

/* LOG OG JSON FILE */
console.log(newJSON);

/* DEEP CLONE JSON FILE - MAKES A COPY */

let deepCloneJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newJSON));

/* DELETE FROM THE COPY, NOT THE ORIGINAL */
delete deepCloneJSON.members[1];
console.log(deepCloneJSON);

/* CHECK THE ORIGNAL IS STILL INTACT */
console.log(newJSON);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pixelmedia/7j18y5sp/12/

Old responses due to vague question:

Your question seems rather confusing, but if you are trying to delete from your JSON, then use the following.

Example: This will delete the second, and leave the first (0).

```
delete originalJSON[1];
```

Another example:

Initial is: 1, 2, 3

```
const originalJSON = [1, 2, 3];
delete originalJSON[1];
console.log(originalJSON);
```

Expected output: 1, 3

Now updated to demonstrate with the additional information provided by the OP:

```
const newJSON = {
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "available": "true",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "TinyruthlessPC",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Tester",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tinyruthless",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Photography",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kade",
      "instagram": "Kade_Sucks",
      "signupDate":"April 11, 2021"
    }
  ]
}

delete newJSON.members[1];
console.log(newJSON);
```

Expected output: removed 'Tinyruthless'

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pixelmedia/7j18y5sp/1/

Comment: I think the problem the OP has is that it's modifying both originalJSON and newJSON because the are references to the same object.

Comment: Thanks Daformat. Have updated again. Trying to decipher the question is harder than providing an answer.

Comment: You're very welcome! I suggest you edit it once more to make it adapted to the OP's concerns: he's got a file, which is JSON, so instead of stringifying back I would keep the file's text content pre-parsing within a variable and then parse it twice, within separate variables.

Comment: `const file = fs.readFileSync(name).toString()` and then `const original = JSON.parse(file)` and `const new = JSON.parse(file)`
Feel like posting a new answer would add to the confusion

Answer (score 0):

so my json will look like this:

```
{
  "howToUse": ",,photos {name} {instagram}",
  "date": "April 8, 2021",
  "available": "true",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "TinyruthlessPC",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Tester",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tinyruthless",
      "instagram": "Xclusiv3_Photography",
      "signupDate": "April 10, 2021"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kade",
      "instagram": "Kade_Sucks",
      "signupDate":"April 11, 2021"
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to make it so that i can go through it and then delete one of the members and keep the rest in the same order

so i thought that i could just do

```
            console.log(`deleteing person`)
            fs = require('fs');
            var name = 'Assets/signup.json';
            var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name).toString());
            const originalJSON = m;

            let newJSONFile = originalJSON;
            console.log(originalJSON)
            
            newJSONFile.members.splice(0, newJSONFile.members.length)

            console.log(originalJSON)
            
            for(m in originalJSON.members) {
                console.log(`for loop runs`)
                if(originalJSON.members[m]['name'] !== args[0]) {
                    let addMember = {
                        "name": originalJSON.members[m]['name'],
                        "instagram": originalJSON.members[m]['instagram'],
                        "signupDate": originalJSON.members[m]['signupDate']
                    }
                    
                    newJSONFile.members.push(addMember)
                    console.log(newJSONFile)
                }else {

                }
            }
```

and it just deletes it from both

Comment: I suggest you add these informations to your original question by editing it instead of making it an answer. This will help everyone :)

Comment: I have now updated my answer below to demonstrate how to remove a specific member from your JSON file. I think this is now what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used below script for this scenario.

```
const orgObj = { foo: "foo", bar: [1, 2, 3] }
var clonedObj = Object.assign({}, orgObj);
clonedObj.bar = Array.from(clonedObj.bar);
clonedObj.bar.push(4);
console.log(orgObj)
console.log(clonedObj)
```

It will make complete saperate copy of you object and OrgObj will remain unchanged.

Comment: Try with `{ foo: "foo", bar: [1, 2, 3] }` and then alter the content of the `bar` array on the copy, then inspect the original, do you see it now? :)